# keep blank cell blank instead of None by python

Tags: python, sql, database, date

I have a access table like this (Date format is mm/dd/yyyy)

**col_1_id-----col_2**

1 1/1/2003

2

3 1/5/2009

4

5 3/2/2008

Output should be a table where Co_1 is between 2 to 4  (Blank cell must be blank)

2

3 1/5/2009

4

I tried with sql query. The output print 'None' in blank cell. I need blank in blank cell.
Other thing is when I tried to insert this value in another table it only insert
rows having date value. The code stops when it gets any row without date. I need to insert rows as it is.

I tried in python with

```
import pyodbc
DBfile = Data.mdb
conn = pyodbc.connect ('Driver = {Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ =' +DBfile
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql_table = "CREATE TABLE Table_new (Col_1 integer, Col_2 Date)"
cursor.execute.sql_table()
conn.commit()

i = 0
while i => 2 and i <= 4:
    sql = "INSERT INTO New_Table (Col_1, Col_2)VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (A[i][0], A[i][1])
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
i = i + 1
cursor.close
conn.close
```

`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `A[i][x]` which dictates the value for you, why not simply add an **OR** logic to eliminate the possibility of `None`.

For any cell you wish to keep as "blank" (assume you mean empty string), let's say `A[i][1]`, just do

`A[i][1] or ""`

Which will yield empty string `""` if the cell gives you `None`.

Answer (score 0):

The string representation of `None` is actually `'None'`, not the empty string. Try:

```
"... ('%s', '%s')" % (A[i][0], A[i][1] if A[i][1] else '')
```

Comment: The `A[i][1] or ''` syntax suggested by @woozyking is actually nicer.

Comment: Why, thank you. Though from a meta perspective, the if else logic matches the way that human processes info better. So both are educational, mine is more 'digital' :)